# how to decode complex json in dart/flutter?

Tags: android, json, flutter, api, dart

After my request to server i get this json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 56012,
        "name": "The name",
        "description": "<p>description</p>\n",
        "regular_price": "45000",
        "sale_price": "45000",
        "tags": [],
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 56043,
                "src": "pic link",
            }
        ],
    },
]
```

i want to decode them and show them on my screen

so my class model is:

```
class ProductModel {
  late int _id;
  late String _name;
  late String _regular_price;
  late String _description;
  late var _image;

  ProductModel(this._id, this._name, this._regular_price, this._description,
      this._image);

  get image => _image;

  set image(value) {
    _image = value;
  }

  String get regular_price => _regular_price;

  set regular_price(String value) {
    _regular_price = value;
  }

  String get description => _description;

  set description(String value) {
    _description = value;
  }

  String get name => _name;

  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
  }

  int get id => _id;

  set id(int value) {
    _id = value;
  }
}
```

now i have decoded this json like this:

```
var bodybytedecoded= jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
 var productItem = ProductModel(bodybytedecoded["id"], bodybytedecoded["name"], bodybytedecoded["regular_price"],bodybytedecoded["description"],bodybytedecoded["image"]["src"]);
```

i can access to id, name , description but i can't use src in image array, and it doesn't load on my screen.

is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
bodybytedecoded["image"]["src"]
```

to

```
bodybytedecoded["images"][0]["src"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
bodybytedecoded["image"][0]["src"] // here you change the index of image
```

Answer (score 0):

bodybytedecoded["image"][0]["id"]   //for id

bodybytedecoded["image"][0]["src"]  // for src

//just print data to console

```
print("${bodybytedecoded["image"][0]["id"]}");
```

//you got 56043,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).